# How can I understand why an edit does not get accepted and a question does not get re-opened?

Tags: discussion, support

How can I understand why an edit does not get accepted and a question does not get re-opened?

A few weeks ago I had edited the closed question [Is it “re-offend” or “reoffend”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/195711/is-it-re-offend-or-reoffend) in order to make it a better fit for being kept open.(*) My edit ended up in the peer-review queue. However I never saw my change accepted.

So now I want to know why my edit was not accepted and subsequently why the question was not e-opened.

How can I find out?

---

(*) Because I think the question is very valid and the answers not just opinion-based - far from it: the answers show research with proper citations/links.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To find what happened to your suggested edits, go to the profile page on the site where you made the suggestion (Main ELU in this case: https://english.stackexchange.com/users/9579). The options available change with reputation level and privileges earned, but there should be enough here for you to navigate around the page.

Click **Activity** in the top line of the profile page:

[image: Screenshot of Activity tab header]

...then **All actions** and **Suggestions** a little further down the page.

[image: Screenshot of Suggestions tab header]

Which will show what's happened to your suggestions, like these for example [these aren't yours]:

[image: Screenshot of suggested edits]

You can click on the words "approved edit" and "rejected edit" to see the result and how reviewers reacted to your suggestion.

In the case of a rejected edit you should find the reason.

Comment: Reviews are public so you might as well link to it: http://english.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/206476

Comment: @curiousdannii So they are; it's a bit difficult to tell what's public and what is not when you have mod privileges, although I could probably have found that review was public, with a bit of lateral thinking.

Answer (score 2):

I will answer the question, "Why was the question not reopened?"

1. If you want to get a question reopened, you can edit the question body, which will automatically make it appear in the reopen votes queue if it is edited within 5 days of closure. For more information on *reopen review queue*, read [How to get a question to reopen review queue?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196677/how-to-get-a-question-to-reopen-review-queue)
2. Since the question was closed longer than 5 days ago, you should post a Meta question to ask users to vote to reopen a closed question.

However, there have been many questions asking about the prefixes such as *re* and *pre* and whether a hyphen is needed after them such as

[Hyphens in verb construction containing prefix such as "re"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/84855/hyphens-in-verb-construction-containing-prefix-such-as-re)

[adding a prefix "re" to a word, with or without a hyphen?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7731/adding-a-prefix-re-to-a-word-with-or-without-a-hyphen)

[Hyphen for re when doing again](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87262/hyphen-for-re-when-doing-again)

[Hyphenation in pre[-]determined](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/323661/hyphenation-in-pre-determined/323664#323664)

I am not sure why it was not closed as duplicate. I would have voted to close it as duplicate, but views of others might differ from my own.

Comment: It only automatically enters the reopen queue if the original poster edits it or if the closing is not longer ago than five days.

Comment: @Helmar I didn't notice the question was asked that long ago when I wrote this answer. I edited it more thoroughly. Thanks.